# android application is unfortunately stopped when receiving GCM notification

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

my android emulator is receiving the GCM notification correctly but when i install the same application on android phone it stops automatically saying unfortunately stopped and notification is not received at all.

Comment: please help i m stuck

Comment: Can you post your logcat?  Or the code where it fails?  Or anything?